# Powershell - select and update an attribute "on the fly"

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to look for AD users who have an null attribute ("terminalservicesprofilepath") and to update this attribute in the same command.

I can select the users, but how to update the attribute "on the fly" ?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(ObjectClass -eq "user") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -server $DC[1] -Properties * | select SAMAccountName,displayName,DistinguishedName,Mail,Homemdb,@{Name="TSP";Expression={([adsi]("LDAP://$($_.distinguishedName)")).psbase.InvokeGet("terminalservicesprofilepath")}} | where {($_.DistinguishedName -match ".OU=USERS.") -and ($_.TSP -eq $null)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't as simple as piping to Set-ADUser. Try this as a script:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)} -server $DC[1] -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=<Domain>,DC=<TLD>" | Select-Object SAMAccountName,DisplayName,DistinguishedName,Mail,Homemdb,@{Name="TSP";Expression={([adsi]("LDAP://$($users.distinguishedName)")).psbase.InvokeGet("terminalservicesprofilepath")}
$nullTSP = Where-Object {$_.TSP -eq $null} 

foreach ($TSP in $nullTSP) {
    $TSP.DistinguisedName.psbase.Invokeset("terminalservicesprofilepath","\\<server>\<share>\")
    $TSP.DistinguishedName.setinfo()
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!